# How can i use fetch() in proper way to get data from web api?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, async-await, fetch

I want to set stock data in `stockData` and print it in console when I submit form.

but when I submit form, I got only `undefined`.

I think it's because it takes time fetch data from api(not sure).

How can I fix this code?

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const MY_API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_API_KEY;

const Home = () => {
  const [stockData, setStockData] = useState();
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!symbol) {
      return;
    }
    const apiCall = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${symbol}&outputsize=compact&outputsize=full&apikey=${MY_API_KEY}`;
    fetch(apiCall)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setStockData(data["Time Series (Daily)"]);
      });
  }, [stockData, symbol]);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(({ symbol }) => {
        setSymbol(symbol);

        if (!stockData) {
          return;
        }
        console.log(stockData); 
      })}
    >
      <label>symbol</label>
      <input {...register("symbol")} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Did you check the network tab in dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching data is asynchronous, so you can't handle the response synchronously in your submit handler like you've tried to now. Even if you were able to fetch that data synchronously, because of the way React's `useState` hooks you still wouldn't be able to access the new value via your state variable immediately anyway, since it won't be set until the component is re-rendered.

The way you are calling `setStockData` within a `useEffect` is mostly correct, but you have set up that hook's dependencies incorrectly. It should depend on `setStockData` but not on `stockData`.

The way you have it currently, your `useEffect` will trigger itself each time it gets a response, because it updates `stockData` and that triggers the hook to run again. Your tab won't freeze up because it's asynchronous, but it's still not what you want to happen. If you watch the network tab in your browser's dev tools, I'd expect you to see an unending series of requests to your stock data endpoint, with a new one fired immediately after the previous one comes back.

If you need to access `stockData` directly in your submit handler... well the bad news is basically you can't. You need to wait until the response has arrived to handle it, and because of the way event handlers work in JavaScript that's not something you can do directly.

Even if you did your `fetch` directly in the handler, handling the response asynchronously comes with some downsides which aren't specific to React, for example it would be too late at that point to call the `preventDefault` method on the event object, if that's something you needed to do based on the response you get.

You need to either use your stock data response within your existing `useEffect`, where you currently call `setStockData`, or set up another `useEffect` hook that depends on `stockData` so it will run each time you update it, and do whatever you need to with that data in there.

For example:

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const MY_API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_API_KEY;

const Home = () => {
  const [stockData, setStockData] = useState();
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!symbol) {
      return;
    }
    const apiCall = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${symbol}&outputsize=compact&outputsize=full&apikey=${MY_API_KEY}`;
    fetch(apiCall)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setStockData(data["Time Series (Daily)"]);

        // Option A: use your data object here
      });
  }, [setStockData, symbol]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stockData) {
      return;
    }

    // Option B: use stockData here
  }, [stockData]);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(({ symbol }) => {
        setSymbol(symbol);
      })}
    >
      <label>symbol</label>
      <input {...register("symbol")} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `stockData` immediately after setting symbol state, but `stockData` state isn't updated synchronously. `useEffect` hook has an asynchronous behaviour, so `stockData` may not have been updated by the time you try to access it in the `handleSubmit` function.

Additionally, it's important to remove `stockData` from the `useEffect` dependencies to prevent potential infinite loops caused by updating `stockData` inside the `useEffect` callback.

If you want to print actual information of stockData in the console, you can use `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(stockData);
}, [stockData]);
```